# Mux and Adder going into Infinite Loop

Tags: verilog, multiplexer, shift-register

I have been trying to learn verilog with help of a project. The mix that takes adder output as input and gives input to adder as per the control signal is going into an infinite loop, but it should only add till count = 9 and then reset. Can someone please point out my mistake?

[image]

Top Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module top(
input CLK,
input RESETn,
input [9:0] imgPixel,
output [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

reg [3:0] counter;
wire select_in_mx1,select_out_mx1,select_in_mx2,select_out_mx2;
wire [15:0] out_csr,in_mx0,out_mx0,in_mx1,out_mx1,in1_mx2,in2_mx2,out_mx2,in1_add0,in2_add0,out_add0;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
cir_shift_reg_v csr (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .RESETn(RESETn),
    .WORD_OUT(out_csr)
);

assign in_mx0 = out_csr;

mux mx0 (
    .WORD_IN1(in_mx0),
    .WORD_IN2(16'd0),
    .SELECT_BIT_IN(imgPixel[count_out]),
    .WORD_OUT(out_mx0)
);  

assign in1_add0 = out_mx0;

counter cnt0 (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .RESETn(RESETn),
    .count(count_out)
);

assign count_in = count_out; 

control crtl0 (
    .counter(count_in),
    .condition(4'd0),
    .SELECT_BIT_OUT(select_out_mx1)
);

assign select_in_mx1 = select_out_mx1;

//assign in_mx1 = out_add0;

mux mx1 (
    .WORD_IN1(16'd0),
    .WORD_IN2(in_mx1),
    .SELECT_BIT_IN(select_in_mx1),
    .WORD_OUT(out_mx1)
);

assign in2_add0 = out_mx1;

adder add0 (
    .count(count_in),
    .WORD_IN1(in1_add0),
    .WORD_IN2(in2_add0),
    .WORD_OUT(out_add0)
);

assign in1_mx2 = out_add0;
assign in_mx1 = out_add0;       

control crtl1 (
    .counter(count_in),
    .condition(4'd9),
    .SELECT_BIT_OUT(select_out_mx2)
);

assign select_in_mx2 = select_out_mx2;
assign in2_mx2 = out_mx2;

mux mx2 (
    .WORD_IN1(in1_mx2),
    .WORD_IN2(in2_mx2),
    .SELECT_BIT_IN(select_in_mx2),
    .WORD_OUT(out_mx2)
);  

assign WORD_OUT = out_mx2;
endmodule
```

Circular Shift Register Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module cir_shift_reg_v(
input CLK,
input RESETn,
output reg [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

parameter initialValue = {16'h0,16'h1,16'h2,16'h3,16'h4,16'h5,16'h6,16'h7,16'h8,16'h9}; 
//This works because concatenation makes it a 160bit wide value.

reg [15:0] wordShiftReg[9:0];
integer i;

initial begin
for (i=0;i<10;i=i+1) begin
    wordShiftReg[i] = initialValue[((9-i)*16)+:16];
end
end

always @(posedge CLK or negedge RESETn) begin
if (RESETn == 1'b0) begin
     for (i=0;i<10;i=i+1)
        wordShiftReg[i] <= initialValue[((9-i)*16)+:16];
     end    
 else begin
     WORD_OUT = wordShiftReg[0]; 
    for (i=0;i<9;i=i+1) begin
        wordShiftReg[i] <= wordShiftReg[i+1];
    end
    wordShiftReg[9] <= WORD_OUT;
 end
 $display ("CSR op = %d",WORD_OUT);  
 end
 endmodule
```

Multiplexer Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module mux(
input [15:0] WORD_IN1,
input [15:0] WORD_IN2,
input SELECT_BIT_IN,
output reg [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

always @(*) begin
$display ("SELECT BIT = %d", SELECT_BIT_IN);
$display ("WORD_IN1 = %d", WORD_IN1);
$display ("WORD_IN2 = %d", WORD_IN2);

WORD_OUT = (SELECT_BIT_IN) ? WORD_IN1 : WORD_IN2;
$display ("MUX op = %d",WORD_OUT);      
end     
endmodule
```

Counter Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module counter(
input CLK,
input RESETn,
output reg [3:0] count
);

always @(posedge CLK or negedge RESETn) begin
if (RESETn == 1'd0) begin
    count <= 4'd9;
end 
else begin
    count <= ((count + 4'd1)%10);
end
//$display ("count = %d",count);
end  
endmodule
```

Control Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module control(
input [3:0] counter,
input [3:0] condition,
output reg SELECT_BIT_OUT
);

always @(*) begin
$display ("Counter = %d", counter);
$display ("Condition = %d", condition);

SELECT_BIT_OUT = (counter==condition) ? 1'd1 : 1'd0;
$display ("CTRL op = %d",SELECT_BIT_OUT);       
end
endmodule
```

Adder Module

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module adder(
input [15:0] WORD_IN1,
input [15:0] WORD_IN2,
output reg [15:0] WORD_OUT
);

always @(*) begin
$display ("WORD_IN1 = %d", WORD_IN1);
$display ("WORD_IN2 = %d", WORD_IN2);
WORD_OUT = WORD_IN1 + WORD_IN2;
$display ("ADD op = %d",WORD_OUT);      
end
endmodule
```

TestBench

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
module tb_top;

// Inputs
reg CLK;
reg RESETn;
reg [9:0] imgPixel;

// Outputs
wire [15:0] WORD_OUT;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
top uut (
    .CLK(CLK),
    .RESETn(RESETn),    
    .imgPixel(imgPixel), 
    .WORD_OUT(WORD_OUT)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    RESETn = 0;
    CLK = 0;
    #10 CLK = 1;
    #10 CLK = 0;    
    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
            //#100;
    #20 RESETn = 1;

    imgPixel = 10'b1000111010;
end    

    // Add stimulus here
always begin
    //if (RESETn == 1'b0) begin
        //CLK = 0;
        //RESETn = 1;
    //end   
    //else
        #10 CLK = ~CLK;
end

// monitor results
always @(negedge CLK)
$display("TOP op = %d\n",WORD_OUT);
endmodule
```

Please point out any good practices and anything else that should be changed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just dumped a load of code here and haven't asked any question

Comment: I am sorry about my post being confusing. My question is why is my counter starts counting before Finishing circuit initialization process.

Comment: Show what you expect to observe, or some waves of the relevant module...

Comment: @SeanHoulihane So one of the most prominent error that I can point out is my Counter starts counting before Initialization process finishes, and therefore the modules are not synchronized properly.

Comment: One small point, you have initial blocks replicating the work of the reset - this is probably harmless, but not necessary. You only need initial to drive CLK and RESETn, everything else can be driven from them. If I read you right, you want to sample the first result when COUNTER==0? This should be happening already, its just your display don't have any defined ordering. If you capture the result in a flop, you might get the result you want.

Comment: What's a better practice? Initial blocks or reset blocks?

Comment: Abuse of asynchronous logic is your issue. If you are feeding the output of an adder back into itself, then it will keep adding over and over again at whatever the propagation delay of the adder path is. In simulation this means it will add every time step. If you want to build an accumulator, you need to add a register stage to the output of the adder so that it will only add once each clock cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you hold the clock low whilst reset is low. This may prevent some stages from resetting properly (there is neither a *posedge CLK* or *negedge RESETn*). Notice that *top reset* doesn't appear in your output. Generally in a real-world power-on sequence, voltage stabilises, clock will be started, and once it is stable and applied to the circuit, reset is de-asserted.
Some circuits explicitly require a number of clock cycles of reset asserted (LOW) in order to initialise pipelines, etc.

```
// Add stimulus here 
always begin 
 // if   (RESETn == 1'b0) 
//      begin CLK = 0; not needed
//       RESETn = 1;  not needed
 // end else  
 #10 CLK = ~CLK; 
end
```

Comment: Thanks @SeanHoulihane for the input, I made a change put putting `RESETn = 0` during initialization and then `RESETn = 1` after the Global Delay, but nothing much changes. Should I increase the global delay or I need to do something else?

Comment: See my edit. I think you actually deassert reset earlier than you want to.

Comment: as per your code should I initialize the reset in initial as 0 or 1. If 0, then where should i make it 1, otherwise the code won't run at all.

Comment: Reset start low, clock low, clock high, clock low, reset high. Other combinations are valid, but that should work. Reset looks like it goes high in your initial block at 50 cycles.

Comment: Do you mean like this?

`initial begin`
`RESETn = 0;`
`CLK = 0;`
`#10 CLK = 1;`
`#10 CLK = 0;`
`#100 RESETn = 1;`
`end`    
  
`always begin`
`if (RESETn == 1'b0) begin`
`//CLK = 0;`
`//RESETn = 1;`
`end `
`else`
`#10 CLK = ~CLK;`
`end`

Comment: but if I keep the If condition to check RESETn == 0, its an infinite loop, and if I remove it, still the counter is counting before the initialization process finishes. I am sorry but I am badly stuck.

Comment: Yes, first make sure the clock runs whilst reset is low, then work out what is a problem for the counter. This is why I suggested looking at waveforms.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the clock and reset are working as they should.